# Oracle 10g - Escape quote in insert statement

Tags: oracle, oracle10g

I am trying to insert people's height into a database in the form of 5'9

How do I properly escape the quote so I can do this. My insert statement looks like this so far.

```
INSERT INTO height(id, height) 
VALUES(height-seq.nexval, '5\'9');
```

The backslash does not work obviously and I am pretty new to oracle. Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Oracle uses standard SQL:

```
INSERT INTO height(id, height) 
VALUES(height-seq.nexval, '5''9');
```

(Yes there are two single quotes)

Comment: is there any oracle function to acheive this ? i m having problem inserting in blob column when there is single quote

Answer (score 2):

if you are doing this from a front end using some programming language, consider using a parametrized query, if you are in psql or some other tool to do this, just use '5''9 ' and it will work fine

Comment: blogspot no no front end yet, just populating my db with some data through SQL developer. But thanks I will def use parametrized queries later down the line.

Answer (score 2):

I hate double quoting, it's a mess. Luckely these days we have the quote operator:

```
q'{delimiter}string{delimiter}'

INSERT INTO height(id, height) 
VALUES(height-seq.nexval, q'#5'9#');
```